# Why can I not remove NaN values from this output list?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am able to remove NaN from my list outputs when the non-NaN values are numerical. But in this case, since letters are involved I keep getting an error.

```
fordnumber1 = orderdetails_df.productcode.where(orderdetails_df.ordernumber.isin(ordnumber))
fordnumber = [row for row in fordnumber1 if not np.isnan(row).any()]
```

Error:

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Also, the output without the exclusion of NaN values.

```
fordnumber1
Out[104]: 
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
       ... 
2991    NaN
2992    NaN
2993    NaN
2994    NaN
2995    NaN
```

I am stumped. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks friends!

Comment: try with `pd.isna()`, it's more flexible

Comment: @Matthew Lynn if you can give a sample of the data in ```fordnumber1``` it'll be easier for others to help figure this out with you

Comment: @cgclip It's an output of 2995 values that look like this:  S18_1749

Comment: @ALollz I'm not too sure how to use that. I have tried multiple ways and I am getting nothing but errors.

Comment: did you try ```fordnumber1.dropna()```? That should handle what you're trying to do with that list comprehension. The error you're running into is likely caused by the object you're iterating over in the list comprehension. If you're curious I'd try to check their types.